# How to create sencha theme from psd design for mobile app

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have psd of mobile design. Following is an example jpeg version of the psd.
[image]

I need to create a custom design in **Sencha Touch 2**. 
So, please help me by guiding step by step process to do the same. 
I mean how do i set custom layout then how do i build custom designed pages, form elements etc. I am very new in sencha.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get me wrong but what you are asking is that someone else does your job.

To make an app that looks like your picture you should take a look at the following components:

- [TabPanel](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel)
- [Container](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Container)
- [Button](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Button)
- [FormPanel](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel)
- [Image](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Img)
- [SelectField](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Select)

If you need an overall tutorial on how to create an app with sencha take a look at [MiamiCoder](http://miamicoder.com/sencha-touch-tutorials/). There is a great tutorial to begin with.